# Does setting Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler prevent Google's error-reporting from work?

Tags: android, exception

In my Android application I utilize `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` to store information about unhandled exceptions locally on a user device. After some feedback I suspect that this code prevents the built-in Google's error-reporting feature from work, because I do not see error reports in the developer console, while exceptions are reported by users. Their devices are well past 2.2, where the error-reporting was introduced. Could it be that specific device with, say, 4.0.3 does not support this feature? If yes, how can I detect this programmatically?

I can't find information regarding this in Android documentation. I'd like both standard error-reporting and my custom handling work together. In my custom exception handler I call `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to get default handler, and in my implementation of `uncaughtException` I propagate exception to this default handler as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will stop the inbuilt error report. The user is given a dialog when your app crashes, with an option to report the error via Google Play. However, if you use `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` then the exception is handled within your app, and no option is given to report it.

I recommend that you integrate [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra) into your project, as it allows you to easily receive error reports upon crashes.

Comment: Hm, do you mean ACRA will allow to see errors both in the developer console and in a custom way? I'd like to preserve standard error-reporting. As to sending reports, I have this custom functionality as well, but I thought it's excessive because of Google's standard feature.

Comment: No. ACRA will not show them in the developer console, but it provides very very detailed reports, containing far more information than the dev console ones

Comment: According to this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11281388/465942 "setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler makes app crash silently") question, calling `System.exit(1);` should work, but I haven't got any luck with it unfortunately..

Answer (score 3):

I first tried calling `System.exit(1);` as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281388/465942), but that didn't work.

Finally solved it by calling the `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)` again on Androids default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (found it by checking the [ACRA source code](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/2d2833284c3466097aa7efcf4e575bae7ca2326d/src/main/java/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java).

**Example Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _androidUncaughtExceptionHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _androidUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);

        // Rest onCreate
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }

    //@Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        try {
            // Do your stuff with the exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* Ignore */
        } finally {
            // Let Android show the default error dialog
            _androidUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    }
}
```