# Android catch unhandled exception and show the dialog

Tags: android, exception

I want to handle unhandled exception in my app without any third-party libraries.

So i write a code.

**Activity :**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ReportHelper(this));
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

**My crash handler :**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.MessageQueue;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by S-Shustikov on 08.06.14.
 */
public class ReportHelper implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final AlertDialog dialog;
    private       Context     context;

    public ReportHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Application was stopped...")
                .setPositiveButton("Report to developer about this problem.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Not worked!
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        System.exit(0);
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                    }
                });

        dialog = builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        showToastInThread("OOPS!");
    }

    public void showToastInThread(final String str){
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                Toast.makeText(context, "OOPS! Application crashed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(!dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.show();
                Looper.loop();

            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

When i start app as you see **i throwed NullPointerException**. `Toast` in my handling logic was showed, and dialog was showed too. BUT! Dialog clicks was not handling correct. I mean logic in `onClick` method was not worked. What the problem and how i can fix that?

Comment: Define what's not correct? What happened and what was the expected behaviour in your onClick behaviour?

Comment: What are you expecting and what do you see ? i.e. why do you say 'it is not working' ?

Comment: @ben75 i expect that the dialog will close and app will be finished on press "Exit" button.

Comment: @MartinKonecny expected behavior i descript in previous answer to ben75. Dialog just showed but clicks not handled.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov Also I have this problem. Do you found any solution?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki unfortunetely no. I do next: show toast about error and save flag into preferences before app was finished. When user launch app in the next time - i show dialog that informate about crash on the last application launch and propose to user send error to me.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov tnx for reply. I found solution. see my answer in below.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I moved `AlertDialog.Builder` in thread run function like this:

```
public void showToastInThread(final String str){
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Application was stopped...")
            .setPositiveButton("Report to developer about this problem.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Not worked!
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.exit(0);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                }
            });

            dialog = builder.create();


            Toast.makeText(context, "OOPS! Application crashed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(!dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.show();
            Looper.loop();

        }
    }.start();
}
```

and all thing work perfectly. 
Hope this help you.

Comment: Did you sure that You handle crash action one time? Because i catch 2-3 exceptions.

Comment: When first exception occur I see alertdialog and with close button listener, kill my app. What do you means with 2-3 exceptions?

Comment: I mean that ARM send to our exception handler 2-3 times `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)`

Answer (score 2):

According [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281388/276949), the state of the application is unknown, when `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is called. This means that your onClick listeners may not be active anymore.

Why not use this method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ReportHelper(this));
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        new ReportHelper(this);
    }
}
```

and remove ReportHelper implementing the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` interface.

Your method of not explicitly catching exceptions can be seen as an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: But click was not handled. I checked that in debug.

Comment: If i remove my ReportHelper i will got a compile error because `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` pass the parameter which implements `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`. I hope you missed this.

Comment: I put the Log into `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)` and i see magic behavior. this method calls 3 times from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Since an exception occurs on the UI-Thread: the state of this thread is probably *unexpected*

So try simply this in your click handler :

```
.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                }
            });
```