# Background Thread keep on running even when app crashed due to unhandled exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have been working on app that has several activities and services.

In one on my activity, I have starting a thread, which is doing some important work for me in background.

Following is code for thread

```
OnCreate()
{
    Runnable runnable = new MyRunnableThread();
    MyThread= new Thread(runnable);
    MyThread.start();
}

private class MyRunnableThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
              //  Doing some work here ..
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Pause of 2 Second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is how my thread is running..

Now i am stopping this thread using following code

```
MyThread.Intrrupt();
```

This will stop my thread to execute ..

In my scenario, sometime when app crashes, these thread keep on running and thus causing misbehave in my app logic..

I want these thread to be stopped immediately in case of app crashes.

Is it the correct way of stopping the thread execution and stop ?

I am using thread in service class also and in state of confusion that there might be multiple threads of same instance running in app at a time because previous was not stopped correctly !!!

Please guide !!!

Comment: Try adding Thread.currentThread().interrupt() before  the FirebaseCrash.report(e) line

Comment: My app not crashing due to exception in thread

Comment: But exception will catch all exceptions no

Comment: You can not stop the main thread while any other thread are running. (All the child threads born out of main thread.) You can use function Thread.join() to keep the main thread waiting while other thread(s) execute.

Comment: `thread.interrupt()` won't actually interrupt your thread. Instead, it will change a flag in your thread object. You have to keep checking whether that flag is changed within your thread, e.g. `while (isInterrupted()) { // do some action, thread is not interupted yet}`. Now, as soon as you perform `thread.interrupt()` your `while` loop won't execute anymore, which will result your thread to be finished. Afaik, there is no way to explicitly kill a thread in java.

Comment: @azizbekian How it will behave in case of app crashes ?

Comment: Thread is not aware about your app crash. It will still continue to execute, unless you handle crash on your own using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110619/android-catch-unhandled-exception-and-show-the-dialog

Comment: How exactly does the app crash?

Comment: What's your service's `onStartComand()` return value?

Comment: @Onik START_NOT_TRICKY